# Получение куки с сайта tastedive.com после авторизации

Tags: cookie

мне требуется получить куки с сайта tastedive.com после авторизации(для передачи в запросы)
я понял что для авторизации нужно получать с ссылки
[account/signin](https://tastedive.com/account/signin)  *_csrf_token* токен  и передавать в пост запрос на логин

Вот curl запрос

```
curl 'https://tastedive.com/complete/email/' \
  -H 'authority: tastedive.com' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'origin: https://tastedive.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://tastedive.com/account/signin?next=https%3A%2F%2Ftastedive.com%2F&trigger=TopBar' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw 'form_type=signin&next=https%3A%2F%2Ftastedive.com%2F&_csrf_token=Y32NYXWT1W&form_js=ihasjs&email=labeg10231%403dmasti.com&password=labeg10231' \
  --compressed
```

А вот курл запрос на который требуется куки

```
curl 'https://tastedive.com/fragment/recommended/qt-h/start-12/rpp-12' \
  -H 'authority: tastedive.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'cookie: tk_r=436542|cc8298b8c6989510340d852eca924706a0f07bca6cb359cf47cbb9f9b37acd2d5a6611a7a47344d8856eaa19b395cc7b76a97931b5cb8e02c962c728d5802389; tk_s=.eJxdUctOwzAQ_BXkc6GOH0ncL6AUilRKHydrs7bbQBpXsVO1qvrvOIIDcNudnRnt7F6JxtA5Hf2nbcmEbDmbbzfrZbYmI6JdZ8OeTGLX29TVJhFoVnEpkdJSlA4KVbIiA1YxVUAuGa2kVcIK4DlzvGROuUxihlBQx5wFdMoY4JZzxzkXmIOlQhhKrUJBK7TSOCwMg1wxTAU4KkoqnKSGO1pxnqe1dt7vGnvvoY97pkOEaIfFns-r-exJTD_O5khn6uUt22B8XDary3ShpEjCxiPE2qecV4J1vOgWDoN0eoLWn3xioO_b2F00ejMMFu-_sB_yog-hhoSHvjL1qQ7JUGf_rO5eqwZCJLcRae05psE-xmOYjMcxwTbp7AP6w3iw8VhDo4cwetDoxu_qVleA6SPDxf_ETYI-2O77F4LnUjBy-wL3iZFe.FWJOtQ._nMrDhp0YQT1-SoKce8hR3MDNmQ' \
  -H 'referer: https://tastedive.com/shows' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

Как получить куки для этого запроса после авторизации?

> tk_r=436542|cc8298b8c6989510340d852eca924706a0f07bca6cb359cf47cbb9f9b37acd2d5a6611a7a47344d8856eaa19b395cc7b76a97931b5cb8e02c962c728d5802389;
> tk_s=.eJxdUctOwzAQ_BXkc6GOH0ncL6AUilRKHydrs7bbQBpXsVO1qvrvOIIDcNudnRnt7F6JxtA5Hf2nbcmEbDmbbzfrZbYmI6JdZ8OeTGLX29TVJhFoVnEpkdJSlA4KVbIiA1YxVUAuGa2kVcIK4DlzvGROuUxihlBQx5wFdMoY4JZzxzkXmIOlQhhKrUJBK7TSOCwMg1wxTAU4KkoqnKSGO1pxnqe1dt7vGnvvoY97pkOEaIfFns-r-exJTD_O5khn6uUt22B8XDary3ShpEjCxiPE2qecV4J1vOgWDoN0eoLWn3xioO_b2F00ejMMFu-_sB_yog-hhoSHvjL1qQ7JUGf_rO5eqwZCJLcRae05psE-xmOYjMcxwTbp7AP6w3iw8VhDo4cwetDoxu_qVleA6SPDxf_ETYI-2O77F4LnUjBy-wL3iZFe.FWJOtQ._nMrDhp0YQT1-SoKce8hR3MDNmQ

Comment: Короче, решил делать через puppeteer

Comment: Оставил puppeteer , реализовал через настройки конфига аксиоса :
`maxRedirects: 0,
            validateStatus: function(status)
            {
                return status >= 200 && status < 303;
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал через настройки конфига аксиоса:

```js
{
    headers: {
        'authority': 'tastedive.com',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        "cookie": response.headers['set-cookie'],
        'origin': 'https://tastedive.com',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    },
    maxRedirects: 0,
    validateStatus: function(status) {
        return status >= 200 && status < 303;
    },
}
```